# electron.ipcMain is undefined in renderer.bundle.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm trying to revive an old, dead Electron project (version 18.0.1) that I inherited from a long-gone team. I'm able get to the project building and can launch the app (Mac ARM.) However, I'm stumped by this error message, that seems to be triggered at some point during the React startup process:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')`

Checking the compiled `renderer.bundle.js`, the problem is here:

`s.ipcMain.on(e, (e,n,...o)=>{`

`e` is an error string: `"REMOTE_BROWSER_WRONG_CONTEXT_ERROR"`

(I have found no reference to this string anywhere on the internet.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoWGg.png)

`ipcMain` is `undefined`. (`s` is the electron instance.)

Here's the context in `renderer.bundle.js` in which it occurs:

```
const B = function(e, i) {
        s.ipcMain.on(e, (e,n,...o)=>{
            let r;
            if (t.isRemoteModuleEnabled(e.sender)) {
                try {
                    r = i(e, n, ...o)
                } catch (t) {
                    r = {
                        type: "exception",
                        value: v(e.sender, n, t)
                    }
                }
                void 0 !== r && (e.returnValue = r)
            } else
                e.returnValue = {
                    type: "exception",
                    value: v(e.sender, n, new Error('@electron/remote is disabled for this WebContents. Call require("@electron/remote/main").enable(webContents) to enable it.'))
                }
        }
        )
    }
```

Nowhere in my TS source code am I referencing `ipcMain`. The only place in my codebase where I appears is in this generated `renderer.bundle.js`.

This is where the `B` function is being called:

```
t.initialize = function() {
        if (T)
            throw new Error("@electron/remote has already been initialized");
        T = !0,
        B("REMOTE_BROWSER_WRONG_CONTEXT_ERROR", (function(e, t, i, n) {
            const o = f([i, n]);
            void 0 !== o && x(e.sender, o)
        }
```

I've never used Electron before this project, but from what I can infer it seems like there might be a problem with the way Electron's `remote` object is being initialised or accessed.

In my `main.ts` file, I'm importing and using `remote` like this:

```
import * as remote from '@electron/remote/main'

let mainWindow: Electron.BrowserWindow;

remote.initialize();
```

Then, I use it in the `createWindow` function like this:

```
function createWindow() {
 
    if (setupEvents.handleSquirrelEvent()) {
        // squirrel event handled and app will exit in 1000ms, so don't do anything else
        return;
    }

    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 700,
        width: 1280,
        minWidth: 1280,
        minHeight: 720,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            plugins: true, 
            nodeIntegration: true, 
            contextIsolation: false,
            backgroundThrottling: false,
            webSecurity: false 
        }
    });

    remote.enable(mainWindow.webContents);

    mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        mainWindow.setMenu(null);
        //mainWindow.maximize();
        mainWindow.show()
    })

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadURL(
        url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, './index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true,
        })
    );

    // Open the DevTools.
    if(isDev()) {
        mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    }

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        mainWindow = null;
    });
}
```

This is where I'm stuck. I don't know Electron well enough to know whether I'm doing something obviously wrong.

If any experienced Electron developers out that could give me hint as to what I could possibly check, I would much appreciate it!